# open projects in visual studio code offline

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual studio code (VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.29.1). But when I launch the visual studio code after disconnecting my laptop from internet, it doesn't open to me. But when I connect to internet and open it, it really open and works properly. So how can I open it when I want to use offline?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7570#issuecomment-422815878

Comment: I tried the links related to this issue. But I did't get any. Please suggest me if there are other options that I may look.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence `But I did't get any`. Is the links not working? Installed version not fixes the issue? Bad option because it's a separate vscode version? Linux distro that can't install `deb`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [ZIP](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=winzip) download instead.

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation but the problem is still there. can you suggest me other option?